# How to adjust width of cells so they do not cut words in Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer

Tags: php, excel, pear, export-to-excel

I am trying to create an Excel sheet using the Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer that comes with Pear.
The sheet is created, and all is OK, Except, My words are being cut and the cells does not adjust their width to accommodate complete words.
I try to open it with Office 2007.
What values do I have to put into the Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Format object for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this with S_E_W. It would be nice if it had the equivalent of Excel's "fit auto" for column/row widths/heights, but it doesn't - you can only set a column to a specific width with `$worksheet->setColumn()`.

You may want to investigate switching to [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). It's still under active development and supports the newest Excel file formats, as well as a more complete API. S_E_W is essentially dead in the water and shoul be considered abandonware now.

Comment: PHPExcel does support autofit for both columns and rows, as well as defined width and height.

Comment: Thanks for the reference for PHPExcel , I'll convert my code to that in the next refactoring cycle of my (huge) project. In the mean time, I used the method you suggested by calculating the max width of each column and applying it at the end, after filling all the data in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to autofit row heights in `Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer`. Apparently it makes a difference to set the `"Worksheet::protect ( string $password )"` flag at the beginning (no autofit for heights) or at the very end (with autofit for heights) of the worksheet.

Comment: New Excell, and excel like software knows how to consume pure HTML. Today I put everything in a HTML and let the Excell do the heavy lifting. My life became so good...

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for it.

```
$columns = 'NOMBRE,APELLIDO,CEDULA';
$arrayColumns = array('NOMBRE','APELLIDO','CEDULA');
$format = $report->workbook->addFormat(array('Align' => 'left', 'size' => 10, 'Color' => 0));
    $col = 2;
    $row = 5;

                foreach($arrayColumns as $columnName){
                    $report->worksheet->write($row, $col, $columnName, $format);
                    $arrayColumnsWidth[$col] = strlen($columnName);
                    $col++;
}


$sql = "SELECT $columns 
                    FROM table" ;   
            $objConnectionSQL->prepareSql($sql);
            $rs = $objConnectionSQL->executeQuery();


$row++;//it brings me to the next row
            while ($data = $objConnectionSQL->getRows($rs)) {
                $col = 2;
                foreach($arrayColumns as $columnName){
                    $report->worksheet->write($row, $col, $data[$columnName], $format);
                    if($arrayColumnsWidth[$col] < strlen($data[$columnName])){
                        $arrayColumnsWidth[$col] = strlen($data[$columnName]);
                    }
                $col++;
                }
                $row++;
            }

foreach($arrayColumnsWidth as $keyCol => $valWidth){
                $this->worksheet->setColumn($keyCol,$keyCol,floor($valWidth));
        }
```

It's a little complex at the beginning but for now is my method to make the width dynamic on each column.
I hope it will help someone.